# iOS - change animation when user taps screen

Tags: ios, animation

Lets say that i have an animation - an image is going from left side of the screen to the right. I would like to make it a little bit interactive - when user taps on a screen i want to change direction of image movement. Whats the best approach to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

What I do in some cases is take the main view of the View Controller, in Storyboard, and change the class type of that UIView to UIControl.

In the code that is accessed as *MyViewController*.view, which you can write:

```
var viewAsControl = myViewController.view as UIControl
```

In Swift or some equivalent of that.

The UIControl subclass of UIView is the hierarchical layer (class) that adds the action/target facilities to a view. For example, UIButton is a UIControl, because it generates events (actions), and it is also a UIView so it can be added as a subview.

Then from the Connections Inspector, accessed via the far right Icon of the far right panel (that is, the panel to the right of the storyboard editor window), I'd select the Touch Up Inside event type or some other event and drag it to an @IBAction tagged function I'd add to the View Controller's source code, to receive the tap event.  From that tap notification, you can cancel the current animation and add a new one, etc...

Alternatively, you can create an IBOutlet for the view if you've turned it into a UIControl in IB, and use the addTarget() method to assign an action handler for a specific event, e.g. to make it call a function in your code.

Either way the effect will be that any time the view is tapped, it will generate the event for you to respond to